# Refresh Page attributes using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts, reload

I have a scenario where I need to make a call to Java method and check whether a call is finished or not. If it's finished, I need to display a message. This can be done easily using ajax function. but the problem is, I will be setting some request parameters in this method, will they get reflected after ajax.

One more doubt is, how can I control the polling interval for this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
 </script>
```

I want to execute this refresh script only if

```
<s:if test="#request['Isam2Asam'] != null">
```

else the page should never be reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax can easily send request parameters.

You are looking for setInterval though - jQuery version:

```
var tId = setInterval(function() {
  $.get("somejsp?parm="+someParm,function(data) {
    if (data=="done") { 
      clearInterval(tId); // stop polling
      $("#message").html("Done"); // update a div id="message"
    }
  });
},60000);
```

Comment: `$.get`'s result will be a string. `$.getJSON` results to object.